# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') error message when using useState command in a component file

Tags: reactjs

I get the `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')` error message when using `React.useState()` command when used in ReactJS component file, but not when I paste the same component code in the main index.js file. It also accepts the similar command from other files, but not from Meme.js file with code shown below. I use VS Code. What's the problem?

Meme.js ⬇

```
import React from "react";
import memesArray from './memesData.js';

function Memef (){
    const urlnew = memesArray [1].url; 
    
    const [meme, setMeme] = React.useState({
        toptext: "",
        bottomtext: "",
        url: "https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Woman-Yelling-At-Cat.jpg"
    });
  
    function getMemeImage(){ 
            
        setMeme(prevmeme => {return {...prevmeme, url: urlnew}})
    }
  
    return(
        <main>
            <div className='form'>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Top text'></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Bottom text'></input>
                <button onClick={getMemeImage}>Generate</button>
            </div>
            <img className='meme' src={meme.url}></img>
            <p>{meme.toptext}</p>
            <p>{meme.bottomtext}</p>
        </main>
    )
  }

export default Memef ();
```

index.js ⬇
[image: index.js]

As I said, similar `useState` command works from other components' files, and from the main app file.

I also checked similar questions on stackoverflow and google search, and tried different changes, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: When exporting the component at the end, you should not invoke it with `()` as it will cause it to immediately execute. Instead, it should just be `export default Memef;`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it is a typo, but your export statement seems to be incorrect. It should be `export default Memef`